# get enabled user from OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How would I add filter on this to query only enable users ?

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “ou=Users,dc=qq,dc=com”).count
```

Comment: Try `-Filter "Enabled -eq $true"`. As aside, don't use curly quote thingies in code like you have around the SearchBade path, but use straight ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell it to look at the `Enabled` property in the `-Filter` parameter:

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq $true" -SearchBase "ou=Users,dc=qq,dc=com").Count
```

Note that there is no `Enabled` attribute in AD itself. But PowerShell exposes an `Enabled` property that maps to the value in AD (the `userAccountControl` attribute). The actual LDAP query this gets translated to looks something like this:

```
(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)" -SearchBase "ou=Users,dc=qq,dc=com").Count
```

So PowerShell simplifies it a bit for you.

Comment: Excellent ! I'm new to PS. Thanks for your quick response. it was a blocker for me... :)

Comment: does result include sub OU users also ?

Comment: Yes. If you don't want it to, add `-SearchScope OneLevel`